# Fancybox won't respect height

Tags: javascript, jquery, height, fancybox

if I don't set the height of the box and leave it by default: the scrollbar is shown as the box is not big enough

[image]

```
$('#newsletter').fancybox({
    'type': 'iframe',
    'href': 'http://es.solmelia.com/nSubscriber/jsp/C_Subscribe_Newsletter.jsp',
});
```

if I set it to 400:

[image]

```
$('#newsletter').fancybox({
    'type' : 'iframe',
    'href' :   'http://es.solmelia.com/nSubscriber/jsp/C_Subscribe_Newsletter.jsp',
    'padding' : '20',
    'height' : '400'
});
```

(looks way bigger than 400)

also tried

```
$('#newsletter').fancybox({
    'type'              : 'iframe',
    'href'          :   'http://es.solmelia.com/nSubscriber/jsp/C_Subscribe_Newsletter.jsp',
    'height' : '400px',
    'transitionIn'  :   'elastic',
},function(){$.fancybox.resize();});
```

which gives same result as first example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the public method *resize*, once content has been loaded, see method description :

**Auto-resizes FancyBox height to match height of content*

**Ref :** http://fancybox.net/api

**Method Usage :** `$.fancybox.resize();`

What you can try :

```
    $('#newsletter').fancybox({
                        'type'          : 'iframe',
                        'href'          : 'http://es.solmelia.com/nSubscriber/jsp/C_Subscribe_Newsletter.jsp',
                        'scrolling'     : 'no',
                        onComplete : function(){ $.fancybox.resize();}
                });
```

*onComplete - Will be called once the content is displayed*

Comment: Where exactly did you add the resize method, and when do you call it?

Comment: See updated answer. You must use onComplete and then call the method.

Comment: edited your answer with a working solution i found, i guess this has to be it

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue you have here is actually inside the iFrame not fancybox. An iframe will not set its dimensions based on the size of the content within. my recommendation would be to avoid iframes as they are almost always problematic

Comment: thanks for you suggestion but and how can i possibly open it with not iframe?

Comment: You can get the content via ajax and wrap it in its own form tag (Unless you are using ASP.NET and have another form tag on the page). This is quite a tricky thing to get going, especially smoothly. If you want to keep the iframe, you really have to set the size of the iframe manually (you cant really do it dynamically when you are loading content from a different site to your current one)

Answer (score 0):

1. Sometimes, It occurs due to zoom.
2. Can you try updating the `'height' : '400px'`. It may works.